Decoding algorithm for cyclic burst error correcting codes
Can anyone provide an explicit decoding algorithm for cyclic burst error-correcting codes, along with a proof?
I have tried researching this on my own, but some sources seem contradictory.
The ALGORITHM I found is the following:
Suppose $\mathcal{C}$ is a $t$-burst-correcting code. Let $v(x) \in \mathbb{F}_2/(x^n-1)$ and denote by $s_i(x)$ the syndrome associated with $x^i\cdot v(x)$. Then

For $i$ ranging from $0$ to $n-1$:

(a) Compute the syndrome $s_i(x)$ of $v(x)$;
(b) If $s_i(x)$ is a burst of lengh less than equal to $e_\mathcal{C}$ (the correction capacity):
i) Set $e(x) = x^{n-i}\cdot(s_i,0)$
ii) Compute $m(x) = v(x) - e(x)$ and stop

Reject $v(x)$, as correction is not possible.

The PROOF I found (though I am not fully convinced about the final part) is the following:
Let $e$ be a burst of length $(n-k)$. This means that $e$ contains a subsequence of length $k$ consisting only of $0$, that is,
$$
e = (\ldots,1,\underbrace{0,\ldots,0}_{k \mathrm{ terms}},1,\ldots).
$$
There exists an $i \in {0,1,\ldots,n-1}$ such that this subsequence of length $k$ consisting only of $0$s is located at the end of the word $\sigma^i(e)$. Thus, this new sequence has the form
$$
\sigma^i(e) = (\ldots,\underbrace{0,\ldots,0}_{k \mathrm{ terms}})  = (f,0)
$$
where $f$ is the burst of length $(n-k)$ containing the nonzero components of $e$. Then,
$$
\deg\left(f(x)\right) \leq n-k-1 = \deg\left(g(x)\right)-1
$$
which implies that the Euclidean division of $f(x)$ by $g(x)$ is given by
$$
f(x) = 0 \cdot g(x) + f(x).
$$
Thus, the syndrome of $f(x)$ is $f(x)$ itself. Since $f(x) = x^i\cdot e(x)$, we have
$$
e(x) = x^{n-i} \cdot f(x)
$$
Edit:
For precision: $s_i$ is the syndrome associated with $x^i \cdot v(x)$.
There is a Theorem which tells us that the syndrome of $x\cdot v(x)$ can be calculated as follow:

$x \cdot s(x)$ if $\deg(s(x)) < n-k-1$;
$x\cdot s(x) - g(x)$ if $\deg(s(x)) = n-k-1$;

where $s(x)$ is the syndrome of $v(x)$ and $g(x)$ is the generator polynomial (in other words: $v(x) = a(x)\cdot g(x) + s(x)$ for a polynomial $a(x)$.

Please tell us what you understand by the syndrome $s_i(x)$ as it is used in the algorithm. There are many equivalent parity-check matrices for a linear code and which one of these  is used to define the syndrome mattes a lot.

Hi - $s_i$ is the syndrome associated with $x^i \cdot v(x)$. There is a Theorem which tells us that the syndrome of $x\cdot v(x)$ can be calculated as follow:

$x \cdot s(x)$ if $\deg(s(x)) < n-k-1$;
$x\cdot s(x) - g(x)$ if $\deg(s(x)) = n-k-1$
where $s(x)$ is the syndrome of $v(x)$ and $g(x)$ is the generator polynomial.


For $i$ from $0$ to $n-1$ ... note $s_0(x) = s_{n-1}(x)$. Let $e$ be a burst of length $(n−k)$ ... note the maximum burst length is $(n−k)/2$ .

I think what @DilipSarwate is asking is if $s_0(x) = v(x) \mod g(x)$ or if $s_0(x) = v(x) \cdot x^{n-k} \mod g(x)$ or ...

I updated my answer. Short version - I'm not aware of any proofs for actual decoding algorithms, other than doing a brute for check for all bursts $\le t$ .

Algorithms:
Generate syndromes, two main methods:
Method 1: (common software implementation)
$s_{0}(x) = v(x) \mod g(x)$
for $i$ from $1$ to $n-2$ : $s_{i}(x) = x \cdot s_{i-1}(x) \mod g(x)$
$s_{n-1}(x) = s_0(x)$
Method 2: (common hardware implementation)
$s_{n-k}(x) = v(x) \cdot x^{n-k} \mod g(x)$
for $i$ from $n-k+1$ to $n-1$ : $s_{i}(x) = x \cdot s_{i-1}(x) \mod g(x)$
$s_0(x) = s_{n-1}(x)$
for $i$ from $1$ to $n-k-1$ : $s_{i}(x) = x \cdot s_{i-1}(x) \mod g(x)$
In order for $e(x) = x^{n-1-i} \cdot s_i(x)$ to hold, $s_{n-1}(x)$ is used instead of $s_0(x)$.
Decoding, two main methods:
As syndromes $s_1(x)$ to $s_{n-1}(x)$ are generated, check to see if the leading $n-k-e_c$ symbols of $s_i(x)$ are zero, and if so, $e(x) = x^{n-1-i} \cdot s_i(x)$.
As syndromes $s_{n-k}(x)$ to $s_{n-1}(x)$ are generated, check to see if the trailing $n-k-e_c$ symbols of $s_i(x)$ are zero, and if so, $e(x) = x^{n-1-i} \cdot s_i(x)$. Syndromes $s_1(x)$ to $s_{n-k-1}(x)$ are not used. This method needs to be modified to handle bursts that occur in the trailing $n-k-e_c$ parity symbols of $v(x)$.
Proof:
A proof for any specific implementation of a decoder is a brute force check for all bursts $\le t$. There are explanatory proofs for requirements such as $n-k \ge 2 \cdot t$, but not for actual implementations (other than a brute force check).
